# SQL query tune to replace UNION - Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, performance, plsql, performance-tuning

```
SELECT FN_ENQDATA_STRING (col1)
FROM tab1
WHERE tab1.col2 = tab2.col2
AND tab1.col3 = ?
```

I also have tab2 which has same columns as tab1 and i need to call function for that too. What I can do is

```
( SELECT FN_ENQDATA_STRING (col1)
FROM tab1
WHERE tab1.col2 = tab2.col2
AND tab1.col3 = ?
UNION
SELECT FN_ENQDATA_STRING (col1)
FROM tab2
WHERE tab2.col2 = tab2.col2
AND tab2.col3 = ? )
```

Tab1 and Tab2 have same column but no same values
But I need another option because union is taking too long.

Comment: What does The Plan look like? What does `FN_ENQDATA_STRING` do? If you know `tab1` and `tab2` have different values, why are you applying `distinct` to the results?

Comment: actually its a view which gets data based on different year. Hence the distinct.

Comment: `UNION` does remove duplicate results, which adds additional steps to the query plan. If the branches of the union return different results (or they do return some identical rows and you do not care) then you could try `UNION ALL` instead. It may (or may not run faster).

Comment: On the other hand your query makes little sense. The first branch of the union matches tab1 and tab2, but does not read from tab2. The second branch compares a column of tab2 with itself.  Maybe it would be better if you told us what those tables contain and what exact business problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: And you talk about a `DISTINCT` but that no longer appears in your query ? Did you change the question after the comments ? That is very bad form: when you do so, then explain what you changed and why (use a “edit” line at the end).

Comment: Finally: what does « taking too long » means ? How long does it take ? How long would you like it to take ? How big are those tables ?

Comment: Your queries look wrong, as each has a join predicate `tab1.col2 = tab2.col2` despite there only being one table being selected from. Please edit your queries to represent your actual case.